# How do I close a batch file called from another batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file executing the following:

```
curl.exe -o file.bat https://www.examplewebsite.com/file.txt/
start /min file.bat /c
exit
```

And in "file.bat", the last part of the code is:

```
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

What I'm trying to make "file.bat" do is delete itself, and that part works. But then the command prompt window is still open, when I want it to close.

Anybody that can help me? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are including a `/c` argument to `file.bat`, because you aren't using one. I'm also not sure of the purpose of `&exit /b`. Also the best way I've found to get a batch file to delete itself is simply `(GoTo) 2>NUL & Del "%~f0"`.

Comment: @Compo It deletes itself, but the window doesn't close. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: That all depends upon the content of the batch file you have the `start /min file.bat /c` line in, and how exactly it is being invoked. Neither of those things have been provided, so we are unable to ascertain a solution without that information.

Comment: @Compo I'm sorry, I updated the post. So I want to download a file, run the file and then make sure everything closes up nice and tidy, but the problem is cmd never closes.

Comment: So your `curl.exe` command is downloading a batch file, and then running it, which subsequently deletes itself. Everything about what you're doing is ringing alarm bells, so on this occasion, I'm sorry, but I do not wish to provide further assistance with your task.